# How to specify a constant is a byte or short?

Tags: java

For the long data type, I can suffix a number with L to make the compiler know it is long.  How about byte and short?

As motivation, the following yields a type-mismatch error:

```
List<Short> a = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you are actually talking about is an integer *literal* ( `1` ) versus a long *literal* ( `1L` ).  There is actually no such thing as a short or byte literal in Java.  But it *usually* doesn't matter, because there is an implicit conversion from integer literals to the types `byte`, `short` and `char`.  Thus:

```
final byte one = 1;  // no typecast required.
```

---

The implicit conversion is only allowed if the literal is in the required range.  If it isn't you need a type cast; e.g.

```
final byte minusOne = (byte) 255;  // the true range of byte is -128 .. +127
```

There are other cases where an explicit conversion is needed; e.g. to disambiguate method overloads, or to force a specific interpretation in an expression.  In such cases you need to use a cast to do the conversion.

Your example is another of those cases.

---

But the bottom line is that there is no Java syntax for expressing `byte` or `short` literals.

Comment: "it doesn't matter" -- it does if you're trying to use the literal as an argument to a method or constructor. :(

Comment: @yshavit As for example in Junit: `assertEquals((Short) (short) 2, myCalculatedShortPrimitive());`

Comment: @yshavit Yes, surprising and disappointing that it won't similarly do an implicit conversion when supplying as an argument.

Comment: @yshavit - He could always *float* the idea of a language enhancement, bit I'd give *long* odds of it succeeding.

Comment: @StephenC You'd have to really _double_  down.

Answer (score 5):

[It's done automatically for you at the point of use](http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/lang/literals.html)

> If an int literal is assigned to a short or a byte and it's value is
>   within legal range, the literal is assumed to be a short or a byte.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"404 Not Found"*.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
public static final byte CURRENCY_SYMBOL = 26;

public static final short MAX_VALUE = 3276;
```