# Why does Short.valueOf(n) need a cast

Tags: java, casting

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860948/how-to-specify-a-constant-is-a-byte-or-short) an int constant is implicitly converted to short type.

But in my unit test I want to test a getValue() function which returns a **Short**.

```
assertEquals(obj.getValue(), 42);
```

Obviously the above doesn't work, so I attempt to use Short.valueOf

```
assertEquals(obj.getValue(), Short.valueOf(42));
```

Yet, this still complains - despite the aforementioned implicit conversion - so I have to cast the literal.

```
assertEquals(obj.getValue(), Short.valueOf((short)42));
```

Short.valueOf((short)5) seems a bit messy! Is there a cleaner way? ( new Short("42") equally horrible! )

Comment: It needs a cast, because **literal integer** values are treated as `int`, so you need to tell the compiler that it is actually a `short`.

Comment: Related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317816/why-are-there-no-byte-or-short-literals-in-java

Comment: Take a look at Integer Literals in the JLS: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because converting a number from `int` to `short` may fail (overflow) as it's a [narrowing primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3). In theory the compiler could recognise that the argument is a constant expression and it could determine whether the conversion is valid at compile time. But it doesn't.

A cleaner way is:

```
Short s = 42; //autoboxing is done here
assertEquals(obj.getValue(), s );
```

The reason the above works is that the [rules for variable assignment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) are different. Here the compiler does indeed check whether the constant expression can be converted to `short` without overflow.

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type
>   byte, short, char, or int:
>
> A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the
>   variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant
>   expression is representable in the type of the variable.
>
> A narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion may
>   be used if the type of the variable is:
>
> Byte and the value of the constant expression is representable in the
>   type byte.
>
> **Short and the value of the constant expression is representable in the
>   type short.**
>
> Character and the value of the constant expression is representable in
>   the type char.

The case in bold applies here.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers explain why you have this problem. A cleaner option for your code might be:

```
assertEquals(obj.getValue().intValue(), 42);
```

Although as [biziclop points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254464/why-does-short-valueofn-need-a-cast/26254580#comment41185294_26254580), this would throw a NullPointerException if `getValue()` returns null. While this would still fail your test, it won't be so obvious what has gone wrong.

Of course, if null values are not allowed, you should return a `short` not a `Short`. In which case, you wouldn't need any casts:

```
assertEquals(obj.getValue(), 42); // fine, if getValue() returns a short
```

Comment: That'll throw an NPE is `obj.getValue()` is `null`

Comment: @biziclop Good point, that wouldn't be ideal. Although the test would still fail :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no method in Short class that takes `int` as the paramter , so

```
Short.valueOf(1); // compilation error
```

but casting to `(short) 1`

```
Short.valueOf((short) 1);
```

works because there is a method that takes short as the parameter. Why is that compiler cannot do casting  automatically for you because

> A narrowing primitive conversion may lose information about the
>   overall magnitude of a numeric value and may also lose precision and
>   range.

Answer (score 0):

The [JLS states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1).

Therefore you need to cast it to `short`.

Maybe you are also interested in [Why are there no byte or short literals in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317816/why-are-there-no-byte-or-short-literals-in-java)