# Denote method parameter as "short" primitive type

Tags: java, primitive-types

I have a method that accept one parameter of type `short`.

```
public void doSomething(short value) {
   //DO STUFF
}
```

And I can call it this way:

```
short value = 3;
doSomething(value);
```

But not this another one:

```
doSomething(3);
```

Why? Is there a way to denote that this parameter is a `short` and not an `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason

```
public void doSomething(short value) {
   //DO STUFF
}
```

can be called as

```
short value = 3;
doSomething(value);
```

cause value is already `short`

When you call it like `doSomething(3);` 3 is considered as integer and cannot be casted to short implicitly.

Basically `doSomething(3);` would require a

```
public void doSomething(int value) {
   //DO STUFF
}
```

method to go with.
However you can cast 3 to short and can call the method as:
`doSomething((short)3);`

Comment: Thanks. Why there is not a way to denote a literal as `short` like `f` suffix in `float` types?

Comment: @bigdestroyer The suffix does not have any special name in the Java Language Specification. Neither is there suffixes for any other integer types. So if you need short or byte literal, they must be casted

Comment: @DarshanLila _Neither is there suffixes for any other integer types_: what about `1L`?

Comment: @BenWin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860948/how-to-specify-a-constant-is-a-byte-or-short

Comment: @DarshanLila I know ;). I just said that there is a suffix for an "_integer type_" -> `L`

Comment: But, why? There is `f` for float, `d` for double, `L` for long, why there is nothing for short? Is there any reason?

Answer (score 5):

You can call it this way :

```
doSomething((short)3);
```

Without casting, `3` will always be an int literal.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, arithmetic expressions on the right hand side of the assignment evaluates to `int` by default. Look at this surprising example:

```
short a = 1;
short b = 2;

short c = a + b; // Error!
```

You need to *explicitly* cast to `short` as already mentioned in other answers, or change the method's signature to accept `int` instead.

It's worth mentioning that in terms of space `short` takes the same space as `int` if they are local variables, class variables or even instance variables since in  most systems, variables addresses are aligned, I would simply change the signature of the method to accept an `int` instead and wouldn't complicate things.