# java negative binary literal

Tags: java

So to convert a positive binary number into a negative one I have to invert all of the bits of the number and ​add 1.

```
   `byte x = 0b0111_1111;
    System.out.println(x); // 127
    
    x = 0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1000_0001;
    System.out.println(x); // -127
```

I don't understand why I have to expand my number to 32 bit form by adding zeros on the left side before reversing the bits, why exactly to 32 bit form?

Comment: You don't, you can write `x = (byte)0b1000_0001;`.

Comment: Also check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860948/how-to-specify-a-constant-is-a-byte-or-short

Comment: Because the binary literal is of type `int`, which is 4 bytes, which is 32 bits.